# lettering.js not working if called after page load

Tags: javascript

I'm including both lettering.js and jquery.js properly but the `lettering()` method only works in the html page header like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divCont").lettering("words");
});
```

which is undesirable for me. When I try to call it later through a user clicked button in a function like this:

```
function lettering() {
    $("#divCont").lettering("words");
}
```

I get a

```
TypeError: $(...).lettering is not a function
```

error message. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Is there a solution to this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the snippet below, it does work.

I used the created classes to color the words.

```js
const btnLettering = document.getElementById('btnLettering')

btnLettering.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  lettering()
})

function lettering() {
  $("#divCont").lettering("words");
}
```

```css
.word1 {
  color: red;
}

.word2 {
  color: green;
}

.word3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.6.1/jquery.lettering.min.js"></script>

<div id="divCont">LETTERING BY WORDS</div>
<button id="btnLettering">START LETTERING</button>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work on me, in my effort to find out what is going on, I can see that it only works if jquery and lettering js are included in separate files, if they are in the same js file it throws the error